# How do I get the triangle array outside so that I can use it

Tags: javascript, arrays, closures

I am storing some ID's to an array. The array is correctly populated, but I am not able to log it outside nor use it. I am slightly confused. Here is my code,

**JavaScript**

```
function storeTriangle() {
    var triangle = [];
    return function storePolygons() {
        for (var i = 0; i < 31; i++) {
            triangle[i] = s.select("#triangle36_" + (224 - i) + "_");
        }
    };
    storePolygons();
};
var polygons = storeTriangle();
polygons();
```

Comment: ` storePolygons();` never gets invoked because it is after the `return` statement.

Comment: `but I am not able to log it outside nor use it` - log the array? Where are you trying to log?

Comment: I am trying to `console.log(triangle)` below `polygons()` but I don't get anything displayed.

Comment: @ThomasSebastian `triangle` is within the `storeTriangle` scope so it is not accessible outside of the function or after the return statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function storeTriangle() {
        var triangle = [];
        return function() {
            for (var i = 0; i < 31; i++) {
                triangle[i] = s.select("#triangle36_" + (224 - i) + "_");
            }
          return triangle;
        };
    };
    var polygons = storeTriangle();
    var triangle=polygons();
console.info(triangle)
```